# c++多相的(ポリモーフィズム)という用語の意味

Tags: c++

オブジェクト指向の多相的なんですが、オーバーライド、オーバーロードのことを総称して多相的になると見たのですが。詳しく知りたいです。またポインタではどうなるのでしょか？
以下のコードにオーバーライドと、オーバーロードのことについては理解しています。

```
        class Base {//基底、親クラス
        public:

            void ff() { cout << "Base::ff()\n"; }
            virtual void f() { cout << "Base::f()\n"; }



        };

        class Derive : public Base {//派生、子クラス
        public:

            void ff() { cout << "Derive::ff()\n"; }
            virtual void f() { cout << "Derive::f()\n"; }

        };


        int main() {

            Derive dd;
            Base *bp = &dd;
            Base *bpp = new Base;


            bp->f();

            bpp->f();

            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: 具体的にどういう部分が分からないのかはご説明頂けますか？　単に辞書的な説明では上手く理解できなかった点を教えて頂けると、より効果的な回答ができると思います :)

Comment: その辺詳しく説明するとなると教科書が1冊書けちゃいます。で、実際教科書読んでわからないから質問に至っているのだと思いますのでオイラが教科書書いても同じ結果になるでしょう。具体的にどこがよくわからないか、もう少し絞っていただかないと皆様も回答しづらいかもしれません。